# Nonlinear ordinary differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this

$$y''=-2xyy'$$

I think I can reduce it to first order

$$(y'+xy^2 - \frac{1}{3}y^3)'=0$$
$$y'+xy^2 - \frac{1}{3}y^3 = C$$

Can I do anything else with it?

Comment: What happens when you take the derivative of the second expression you have?

Comment: @NinadMunshi I apologise. I corrected. Do you think this can be solved?

Comment: This might help https://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0321.pdf

Comment: The equation is generalized homogeneous, and therefore reducible by one order. Take the transformations $y=x^{-2}z(t)$, $x=e^t$, then $z'_t=p(z)$ to arrive at a (likely unsolvable) Abel equation of the second kind.

Comment: Given by $pp'_z+(2z-5)p=4z^2-6z$.

Comment: so no solution then?

Comment: An implicit homogeneous solution can be found (to your reduced ODE) but I can't go any further with it unfortunately.

Comment: ```(-(((-3)^(1/3)
        x AiryAi[((-3)^(2/3) x^2)/(2 2^(1/3)) - (-3)^(2/3)/(
         2^(1/3) y[x])])/2^(2/3)) + 
     AiryAiPrime[((-3)^(2/3) x^2)/(2 2^(1/3)) - (-3)^(2/3)/(
       2^(1/3) y[x])])/(-(((-3)^(1/3)
        x AiryBi[((-3)^(2/3) x^2)/(2 2^(1/3)) - (-3)^(2/3)/(
         2^(1/3) y[x])])/2^(2/3)) + 
     AiryBiPrime[((-3)^(2/3) x^2)/(2 2^(1/3)) - (-3)^(2/3)/(
       2^(1/3) y[x])]) + C[1] == 0```